# Show silverstripe ModelAdmin by default

Tags: silverstripe

I want to have a ModelAdmin interface show up as the default rather than Pages - is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the default admin panel by adding the following your `config.yml` file:

```
AdminRootController:
  default_panel: 'NumberOneSuperAwesomeAdmin'
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can set the default login destination in your config.yml like this:

`Security:
  default_login_dest: 'admin/mymodeladmin'`